# How to animate scrambling letters on its position in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I wanted to create animation in which random letters scramble at its position and stops at a specific letter.
Can this be achieved using UIView.animate?
Given below is a rough idea work with.

[image: something like this]

Comment: If I wrote answer to this code that would just scramble the letters randomly and have different lengths, but not be able to randomly form words would that be ok? I really like this idea.

Comment: can you check these two links and tell me whether you want something like that?  https://github.com/franklinsch/iOSDrawTextAnimation  https://github.com/chuganzy/ShuffleTextLabel

Comment: @AaronZheng Thanks and Yeah, it will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really like this inspiration. There are still two ways to put this in your app:
1) Here is code that I created for your instance:
import UIKit

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let listOfRandomLetters = ["@", "%", "*", "^", "1", "2", "3", " ", " "]
    var textNeedDisplaying = ["String", "Other Person", "Sample", "String", "Other Person", "Sample", "String", "Other Person", "Sample", "String", "Other Person", "Sample", "String", "Other Person", "Sample", "String", "Other Person", "Sample", "String", "Other Person", "Sample"]
    var newList: [String] = []
    var incrementer = 0
    var internalTimer: Timer?
    var timer: Timer?
    var mainTimer: Timer?
    @IBOutlet weak var animatingLabel: UILabel!
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        schedule()
    }

    func schedule() {
        //Main Timer interval usually adds up the other two intervals
        self.mainTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true, block: { _ in
            //Play around with the time Intervals
            self.internalTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.1, repeats: true, block: { _ in
                for _ in 0...arc4random_uniform(UInt32(10)) + 1 {
                    let randomNumber = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.listOfRandomLetters.count - 1))
                    self.newList.append(self.listOfRandomLetters[Int(randomNumber)])
                }
                self.animatingLabel.text = self.newList.joined()
                self.newList.removeAll()
            })
            //Play around with the time Intervals
            self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.7, repeats: false, block: { _ in
                if self.incrementer != self.textNeedDisplaying.count - 1 {
                    self.internalTimer?.invalidate()
                    self.animatingLabel.text = self.textNeedDisplaying[self.incrementer]
                    self.incrementer += 1

                } else {
                    self.timer?.invalidate()
                    self.internalTimer?.invalidate()
                    self.mainTimer?.invalidate()
                    self.animatingLabel.text = "DONE"
                }
            })
        })
    }
}
```

If you want the individual letters to animate let me know. I'll make it happen...Make sure that the width constraint for the label is big enough to fit your words. Also if the code can be more concise or better let me know.

2) Use Lottie and after effects for a more customized transition. Let me know if you are interested in this: Link here: https://airbnb.design/lottie/.

Comment: wondering if this can be done using a CADisplayLink instead of a timer!